# Convert data frame columns to vectors

Tags: r

I have a dataframe named "Continents_tmap" where I want to return 3 vectors as per the following examples. Note:the "Values" needs to be Cases as per name in dataframe

```
labels = c("France","Germany","India", etc)
Parent = c("Europe","Europe","Asia",etc)
Values = c(100,345,456,etc)
```

My current code is as follows.

```
covid_1 <-
  read.csv("C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/COVID-19 Activity.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1 <-
  select(
    covid_1,
    REPORT_DATE,
    COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME,
    COUNTRY_ALPHA_3_CODE,
    PEOPLE_DEATH_NEW_COUNT,
    PEOPLE_POSITIVE_NEW_CASES_COUNT,
    PEOPLE_DEATH_COUNT,
    PEOPLE_POSITIVE_CASES_COUNT,
    CONTINENT_NAME
  )

Continents_tmap <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Continent,Country.x) %>%
  summarise(Deaths = sum(Deaths), Cases = sum(Positive_Cases))
Continents_tmap<- data.frame(Continents_tmap)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know how the Continents_tmap data.frame looks like. I assume it is a data.frame with the columns "Continent", "Country" and a value column?
If I get your question right, you can simply get a data.frame column as a vectory like this: ```labels <- Continents_tmap$Country```

Comment: Thanks .... labels <-  Continents_tmap$Country works